# Attach boolean value to each object property

Tags: typescript

Say we have an interface

```
    interface User {
       Id: number;
       FirstName: string;
       Lastname: string;
       Age: number;
       Type: string;
    }
```

and a method that copies desired properties based on a flag.

```
    function copyIfAccepted<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(source: T, dest: T, key: K, 
  isAccepted: boolean) {
      if (isAccepted && source[key] !== dest[key]) {
        dest[key] = source[key];
      }
    }
```

Right now this method is called multiple times for each respective property. Please note that this is not an exhaustive list of all properties.

```
     copyIfAccepted(oldUser, newUser, 'Id', true);
     copyIfAccepted(oldUser, newUser, 'FirstName', false);
     copyIfAccepted(oldUser, newUser, 'LastName', true);
     copyIfAccepted(oldUser, newUser, 'Age', true);
```

How can I refactor this method so it's called once for all properties involved? Using TS 4.9

Comment: I bet you could create a a new type that takes in the arguments type, maps over its values and constructs an interface that removes the original value and replaces it with a bool

Comment: then, you could use that type to decide which values to check and move over

Comment: @DerekPollard Thanks for replying. I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I would create a helper type, that iterates over any type and turns it back into an object with its attributes as booleans for the "isActive" part:

```
interface User {
  Id: number;
  FirstName: string;
  Lastname: string;
  Age: number;
}

type ToBooleanType<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: boolean;
};

function copyIfAccepted<T extends object>(source: T, dest: T, checks: ToBooleanType<T>) {
  for (const key in source) {
    const sourceValue = source[key];
    const destValue = dest[key];
    const isAccepted = checks[key];

    if (isAccepted && sourceValue !== destValue) {
      dest[key] = sourceValue;
    }
  }
}
const user1: User = { Age: 21, FirstName: 'Joe', Id: 1, Lastname: 'Dirt' };
const user2: User = { Age: 26, FirstName: 'Jane', Id: 3, Lastname: 'Doe' };

copyIfAccepted(user1, user2, { Id: false, Age: true, FirstName: false, Lastname: true });

console.log(user1, user2);
```

Output:

```
[LOG]: {
  "Age": 21,
  "FirstName": "Joe",
  "Id": 1,
  "Lastname": "Dirt"
},  {
  "Age": 21,
  "FirstName": "Jane",
  "Id": 3,
  "Lastname": "Dirt"
}
```

Here, we can see that this code does in fact only copy over the attributes that are checked and aren't the same

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-XKk1m82lcowuHEfpWnlTVOiqZC9XIeC2TBTR3kMBQSgQN3Sz1yPMFrVSMO6ktl017DJvOwQAB0tnMwhTXM1GdbuCAA)

Comment: Thanks again for replying. This is great and in line with what I am looking for, one caveat is this is a subset of properties involved, which is unaccounted for, and also getting TS  error: `Argument of type '{Id: boolean, Age: boolean, FirstName: boolean, Lastname: boolean} is not assignable to parameter of type ToBooleanType<Id: number; FirstName: string; Lastname: string; Age: number; Type: string;>` because of property `Type` omission we don't care for. Modified original question.

Comment: Interesting, okay, I think we can probably safely omit the type then in our code, let me update my answer

Comment: As soon as I account for `all` properties error goes away, but I can't have that in my code.

Comment: If I change helper type instead to `type ToBooleanType<T> = {
  [P in keyof Partial<T>]: boolean;
};`  error also disappears. Is that the way to go?

Comment: Sure, alternatively, you could cast the offending object to the correct object, `user1 as User`

Comment: I'd _almost_ say this would be out of scope for this method since its a generic - a way to make sure your types overlap outside would be to either try to cast, in which case, if they don't, TS will yell at you, or to write a converter function to handle going from one to the other

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of borderline, but I am ok modifying helper type as this way it can be used with other object types as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try out this new [typescript playground](https://shorturl.at/qstI6) and see if it addresses your needs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256130/discussion-between-derek-pollard-and-victor).